# Add buttons to Titlebar/Toolbar next to triple-dot-menu in macCatalyst in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, toolbar, navigationbar, titlebar, mac-catalyst

I am trying to create a toolbar for my macCatalyst app in SwiftUI.

On Mac my toolbar should be in the same line as the tripleDotMenu (red, orange, green).
Next to it I want to have my different buttons (see the first image)

[image]

I managed removing my titlebar using:

```
 .withHostingWindow { window in
      #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
           if let windowScene = window?.windowScene as? UIWindowScene {
               windowScene.titlebar?.toolbar = nil
               windowScene.titlebar?.titleVisibility = .hidden
           }
      #endif
  }
```

But I can see that the titlebar is just invisible and not gone (image 2). I am not sure how can can get buttons in the top bar...
[image]
Developing for macOS it happened automatically..
Can someone help me please? A solution in SwiftUI would be amazing.

Comment: This might me a restriction of MacCatalyst. Can't you build a direct macOS target?

Comment: But where is the sense of using macCatalyst then? 
I also want an iPad version... 
But can I add my items to the titlebar somehow instead of adding them to a toolbar under the titlebar?

Answer (score 0):

I have an iOS/MacCatalyst app, using Swift, not SwiftUI.  As soon as I started using Xcode 14, and running on macOS 13 (Ventura), my macCatalyst apps showed the navigation bar menu inline with the 3 dots menu as you say you get for your macOS app.  What Xcode and macOS are you using?

There are some bugs with the new inline navigation menu so I've actually reverted back to the previous menu bar style for macCatalyst which has it below the 3 dots section.  I did this by inserting

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.preferredBehavioralStyle = .pad